# How to choose the large noise when using noise flooding technique in FHE?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto, gaussian-noise

In LWE based multi party FHE schemes, the parties should choose a much larger noise when perform joint decryption. In [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/524.pdf), the author just said that using noise flooding technique to avoid the information leakage about the noise of the ciphertext. Then, how should we choose the smudging noise in a real scenario？

In Palisade library, I find that they add noise with 20-bits standard deviation [Here](https://gitlab.com/palisade/palisade-development/-/merge_requests/273), is it enough to guarantee the security？

Comment: I would recommend you to to join the FHE.org discord server to get answers about any FHE schemes.

Comment: 20 bits sounds very low. You want the statistical distance between two different shifts of the noise distributrion to be "negligible" (like 2^-80). This might help in computing the statistical distance.
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29054/l1-distance-between-gaussian-measures

Answer (score 2):

Using statistical distance yields a crude bound of $\sigma$ noise bits for $\sigma = 2^\lambda$, and [Micciancio and Walter's 2018 Eurocrypt](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/077) paper implies that $\sigma = 2^{\lambda/2}$ is sufficient. Li et al.'s work (https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/816) takes this further and applies it to the $IND-CPA^D$ setting which is the same as the threshold FHE setting, even in BGV/BFV or Regev encryption (we flood to protect the ciphertext noise). Li et al. suggest 47 bits of noise if you can limit the number of queries per ciphertext to $\leq 2^{10}$.

Some more details about the [Li et al. paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/816): they separate the computational security from statistical security described in-detail in Section 4.4. They call this $(\lambda,s)$ where a scheme uses a $\lambda$-bit secure computational assumption (e.g., RLWE) and a $s$-bit secure statistical assumption (regardless of an adversary's time resources). That is, $s$ means that any adversary has at most $2^{-s}$ success probability. Here is where they argue that just under 47 bits of noise flooding is secure in most RLWE settings. This is from the formula
$$
\sigma = \sqrt{24n\alpha}2^{s/2}
$$
where $\alpha$ is the number of adversarial threshold decryption queries per ciphertext, $n$ is the RLWE ring dimension, and $s$ is the statistical security (an adversary has $2^{-s}$ chance of success). Let $n = 2^{15}$ and restrict $\alpha = 1$, then this is about $10 + s/2$ bits for $\sigma$. So, 20 bits in PALISADE corresponds to roughly $2^{-20}$ ($s=20$) success chance for any adversary (somewhat high). Li et al. suggest 47 bits because they set $\alpha = 2^{10}$, $n=2^{15}$, and $s=64$.

A large sigma really only effects performance when using CKKS, since you want the message and the noise to be under $64$ bits so you can use the RNS version with 64-bit native arithmetic. BGV/BFV or Regev encryption aren't as effected since you can just threshold decrypt with an extra RNS modulus or two. I know openFHE (https://www.openfhe.org/) has a 128-bit backend for CKKS. This would allow for a large $\sigma$ and lots of bits of precision for the message in CKKS at a 4-8x slowdown.

Comment: PS - A similar discussion is happening [here](https://openfhe.discourse.group/t/appropriate-error-parameters-for-the-noise-flooding/95)